# Why would @BeanInject not be working with Java 17?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, resttemplate, java-17

I use Apache Camel's BeanInject to initialize my rest template bean object. Like this:

`@BeanInject("restTemplateBean") private RestTemplate RestTemplateBean;`

RestTemplateBean is defined in the  part of the camel xml file and it leads to a RestTemplate class.

But after upgrading to **Java 17**, it just doesn't work anymore, RestTemplateBean comes out as null. Even though it's the exact same setup that worked in **Java 11**. Any ideas? I'm using apache camel 3.11.4 but I've alredy tried using the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Camel 3.11.x does NOT support Java 17, only Java 8 and 11.

Java 17 supports comes first in Camel 3.17 onwards, so you should then use latest Camel 3.21.x if you must use Java 17. Or better upgrade to Camel 4.